# What's a "hit from a quick-freezer"?

Tags: meaning

Could someone please help me with the meaning of this sentence?

"Nate shivered like they’d just been hit by a blast from a quick-freezer."

Comment: Perhaps a blast of cold air from a fan-assisted freezer, which is designed to cool things quickly.

Comment: This is what I pictured when I read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_spray

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 2):

Quick-freezing is a process by which things are frozen quickly. Water freezes at 0 degrees Celcius, so most domestic freezers keep food frozen by maintaining a temperature just below this. 'Quick' freezers subject items to temperatures below minus-10 degrees Celcius. They make things very cold, very quickly, so this seems apt in your example.

Comment: Most domestic freezers easily hit -18°C, and I should find any freezer that does not even reach -10°C unacceptable. A quick-freezer is a different machine altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a freezer a blast of cold air hits your face, which may cause you to feel cold and shiver for a moment. (when you shiver your body vibrates trying to warm you up), So Nate shivered as if he were standing in front of a open freezer. The author (whoever wrote the sentence) istrying to create an image in the reader's mind through visualizing a familiar, everyday thing that might happen to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-freezer or blast chiller is a freezer that works by cooling the products inside by circulating cold air with large fans. A bit like a convection oven.

If you open such a freezer, the cold air will flow out of the door rapidly, which you could call a "blast" of cold air.

So Nathan shivers as if he was exposed to a blast of cold air, like one that could come out of a quick-freezer